# Route 53 multivalue answer record only allows "IP or another value depending on record type" answers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

In AWS Route 53 GUI (newest version as of Oct 17, 2020), I did the following:

- went to my hosted zone
- clicked "create record"
- clicked "multivalue answer"
- clicked select menu that says:

> Value/Route traffic to: The option that you choose determines how Route 53 responds to DNS queries. For most options, you specify where you want to route internet traffic."

All of the options in the select menu were disabled except for "IP address or another value depending on record type", but when I did the same process except using any of the other choices for the routing policy instead of "multivalue answer", all the options are selectable. **Edit:** I am always using A records with each type of routing policy.

When I define the multivalue answer record using a domain name instead of IP I get this error:

> Error occurred
> Bad request.
> (InvalidChangeBatch 400: The RRSet of type A with DNS name multi.dev-recruit.com. cannot be created because multivalue answer sets must contain exactly one resource record.)

When I try to create the record with the invalid answer record from before I get this error:

> Error occurred
> Bad request.
> (InvalidChangeBatch 400: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address) encountered with 'Route-53-test-1835820781.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com')

Is it supposed to be this way so that you have to use an IP address? Why?

Comment: DNS A records are supposed to have IPv4 address values. What exactly are you trying to do? Did you read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multivalue-versus-simple-policies/)?

Comment: Thank you Michael. What I am really trying to do is understand why I can route to other AWS services using A records for all of the routing policy types except for `multivalue`. I read the doc you linked to and did not find the answer. I don't need to use multivalue routing, but I happened to notice this issue and wanted to understand why it is the way it is.